# How can I make my application check for updates at startup and then download it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, clickonce, updates

I tried this:

```
Dim address As String = "http:/test/updateConfirm.txt"
     Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
     Dim updateConfirmVar As String = client.DownloadString(address)
     If updateConfirmVar = "available" Then
```

But I want to do it with the clickOnce update system. How to do it?

Comment: What do you not understand about what you read about ClickOnce when you researched it? If you don't even know that one of the points of ClickOnce is that it will check for updates without you writing any code then you clearly haven't done the appropriate research so it's too soon to be posting a question here.

Comment: but it needs to be uploaded to the internet right?Where to upload it

Comment: That's completely up to you. There's no one magic place that all ClickOnce apps get uploaded to. It just needs to be a server that your users can access. That might be on an intranet for a corporate app or a public web server for anyone to use.